# How to check for double or more times the same item in a list?

Tags: c#

i'm using regex to extract text and adding it to a list :

```
public List<string> GetLinks(string message)
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            string txt = message;
            foreach (Match item in Regex.Matches(txt, @"(http|ftp|https):\/\/([\w\-_]+(?:(?:\.[\w\-_]+)+))([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?"))
            {
                if (item.Value.Contains("thumbs"))
                {
                    int index1 = item.Value.IndexOf("mp4");

                    string news = ReplaceLastOccurrence(item.Value, "thumbs", "videos");

                    if (index1 != -1)
                    {
                        string result = news.Substring(0, index1 + 3);
                        if (!list.Contains(result))
                        {
                            list.Add(result);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return list;
        }
```

i'm trying to check on that line if the result is not exist only then add it to the list but it didn't change much because the list in the end contains over 2000 items some of the at least more then twice in the list :

```
if (!list.Contains(result))
```

so i'm checking for existing item when using it :

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\Videos\");
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                foreach(string text in GetLinks(File.ReadAllText(file)))
                {
                    if (!videosLinks.Contains(text))
                    {
                        videosLinks.Add(text);
                    }
                }                
            }
```

this is working but i wonder if there is a better way to exclude double or more of the same items already when using the regex ?

a side note : how can i make another list that will show me by indexes and strings all the duplicated items including each item name string as it is in the list and the indexs the same items appears ?

Comment: What does "it didn't change much because the list in the end contains over 2000 items some of the at least more then twice in the list" mean?

Comment: Look into `Hashset<T>`. It will probably solve your issues. Or use a Dictionary, with your strings as keys, and a Value of int. Get a string, check if it's in the Dictionary. If it isn't, insert an entry with a value of one. If it is, read and increment the value by one